# How can I go to the login page ? (Symfony 6.0.2)

Tags: symfony, authentication, routes, path, symfony6

I created a route and named it ***login***. So when I created the navbar. I added ***href="{{ path('login') }}"*** for the link that leads to the login page. But when I click on the link, it doesn't lead me to the login page. I stay on the home page.

Where can be the problem ? Thank you for your help. :)

Code in **SecurityController.php** file

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/login', name: 'login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    #[Route(path: '/logout', name: 'logout')]
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

Code in **base.html.twig** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text></svg>">

        {# Bootstrap #}

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

        {# Google fonts #}

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>

    <header class="fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">

            <!-- Home page -->

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('home') }}">
                <img src="/docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
            </a>

            <!-- Bouton de déploiement -->

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto px-4">

                    <!-- Connexion -->

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('login') }}">Se connecter</a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Inscription -->

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">S'inscrire</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
        
        {% block main %}{% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating path for homepage. Change `href="{{ path('home') }}"` to `href="{{ path('login') }}"`.

Comment: Hi Holicz ! Thank you, but I wrote href="{{ path('home') }}" to the link with class="navbar-brand" whigs is good. href="{{ path('login') }}" is indeed written for the connexion button.

Comment: I see now, the first paragraph of your question indicated otherwise. Could you please add output of `bin/console debug:router` to your question?

Comment: Yes indeed ! I replaced it by href="{{ path('login') }}". I have a question. When you say "add output of bin/console debug:router", do you mean I should use it and try it on the terminal ?

Comment: I tried this command : php bin/console router:match /login. It says [OK] Route "login" matches.

Comment: In the end, it worked very well ! My form is not displayed, but I can see /login at the end of the url. So there is no problem after all. :)

Comment: When I said "add output of bin/console debug:router" I meant to run this command in terminal and post the full output. Glad it's working, if my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'home' path is targeting the homepage, you should replace it by 'login' path.

If you need to protect the 'home' route by authentication, you can creates some access control rules: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html